# React Bootstrap Dropdown Working But Won't Display Correct Values (Visual Issue)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-bootstrap

I have a react bootstrap dropdown that is working locally and correctly updates my database, but the dropdown list is visually incorrect. For example, if my dropdown value was "1/8" in the database, it will import correctly, but when I click the dropdown, the list of values are all "1/8" (vs. 1/8, 1/4, 1/2, etc.). If I click any of the values (e.g. third "1/8" in list) the correct value is then shown (e.g. "1/2") but then the list updates to only show "1/2" as every option. On submit, the database updates correctly.

```
{ingredients.map((ingredient, index) => (
 <tbody>
   <td className="ingredientTableSectionAmount">
     <Form.Group controlId='ingredients' className='ingredientsFormGroupAmount'>
       <Form.Control as='select'
         onChange={(e) => {
           ingredients[index][0] = e.target.value;
           setIngredients([...ingredients])
         }}>
         {Quantities.map((quantity) =>
           <option key={quantity[0]} value={quantity[1]}>
             {ingredient[0]}
           </option>
         )}
       </Form.Control>
     </Form.Group>
   </td>
  </tbody>
))}
```

I am almost certain that the issue is related to the use of the embedded map function for my quantities array. For some reason it seems that the ingredient temporarily overwrites the quantity value. Quantity table is below (I am positive it is being imported correctly) and snapshot of the database... I am happy to share more if helpful.

```
const Quantities = [
  ["0", "1/8"],
  ["1", "1/4"],
  ["2", "1/3"],
  ["3", "1/2"],
  ["4", "1"],
  ["5", "2"],
  ["6", "3"],
  ["7", "4"],
  ["8", "5"],
  ["9", "6"],
  ["10", "7"],
  ["11", "8"],
  ["12", "16"],
  ["13", "32"]
]

export default Quantities;
```

[Database Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txVuu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess I am at the point in my development where i can get a good laugh at my own errors. Below is the updated form, incase anyone else runs into the same issues I had. All I had to do was set **value** in Form.Control and just clean up my **option** element.

```
<Form.Group controlId='ingredients' className='ingredientsFormGroupAmount'>
 <Form.Control
   as='select'
   value={ingredient[0]}
   onChange={(e) => {
    ingredients[index][0] = e.target.value;
    setIngredients([...ingredients])
   }}>
   {Quantities.map((quantity) =>
     <option key={quantity[0]}>
       {quantity[1]}
     </option>
   )}
 </Form.Control>
</Form.Group>
```